# How do I include "<" in an XML file quote?

Tags: android, debugging

I get error message for the line:

```
android:text="c. <"
```

This line is in an XML file. When I remove the `<`, I get no error message. I don't know how to correct the mistake.

Comment: Did you try using &lt; instead of < ?. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents) for the rest of characters you need to escape when using XML

Answer (score 0):

`<` cannot be used directly in XML. Try replacing it with `&lt;`

For a more comprehensive answer on XML character escaping, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/1800023)

Comment: First thing when you joined this community, you had to go to [help/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), there it is explained in a simple way.